# Bash pipe: get the exit status of previous process in pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe, exit-code

I am writing a logger that capture the output of a script, and handle that output differently if the previous program fail or succeed:

```
program1 | logger.sh
```

In **logger.sh**, I plan to have something like:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    CAPTURED_OUTPUT="$CAPTURED_OUTPUT\n$line"
done
if "program1 has failed"; then
    echo "$CAPTURED_OUTPUT"
fi
```

How to know **inside logger.sh** that "program1 has failed" ?

Notes that program1 is generic and I have no control about it.

Ideas:

- Is there any signal received on logger.sh side when program1 exit with non-zero status?
- Could I find the PID of "program1" and get its exit status otherwise?
- ...

Comment: Does `logger.sh` do anything else? It would be simpler to do something like `if output=$(program1); then echo "program1 has failed"; echo "$output"; fi`, though it would be more appropriate to use the file system than a shell variable to store an unbounded amount of data.

Comment: Echoing @chepner's comment, can you change the usage to `logger.sh program1` so the script is responsible for starting the program? That would make it a lot easier for it to monitor the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with this:

```sh
program1 > program1.log || cat program1.log
rm program1.log
```

Then you do not need a `logger.sh` at all.

This will redirect the `stdout` of `program1` to `program1.log`, and if `program1` has a non-zero exit code, `program1.log` will be printed. Afterward, `program1.log` is deleted.